# Representation of the Christoffel Symbols

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to follow the proof for this result but I'm not sure about a step.

Let $(M,g)$ be Riemannian Manifold and $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection. Then, the Christoffel symbols for the connection can be obtained as follows:

$$
\Gamma_{ij}^{m} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\partial_{i}g_{jk} + \partial_{j} g_{ki} - \partial_{k}g_{ij}) g^{km}
$$

where $g_{ij} = g(\partial_{i},\partial_{j})$ and $g^{km}$ are the coefficients of the inverse matrix for the metric.

The Christoffel symbols are defined by the equation:
$$
\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\partial_{j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\Gamma_{ij}^{k}\partial_{k}
$$

The book I'm following says that, from this equation, it follows that:
$$
\sum_{l=1}^{n} \Gamma_{ij}^{l} g_{lk} = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_{i} g_{jk} + \partial_{j}g_{ki} - \partial_{k} g_{ij})
$$
and therefore:
$$
\Gamma_{ij}^{m} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\partial_{i}g_{jk} + \partial_{j} g_{ki} - \partial_{k}g_{ij}) g^{km}
$$

**My question is: Why does the first equation follow from the definition?**.

I know that using the Koszul formula we can get:

\begin{align}
g(\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\partial_{j},\partial_{k}) 
& = \frac{1}{2} \biggl(\partial_{i} g (\partial_{j},\partial_{k}) + \partial_{j} g(\partial_{k},\partial_{i}) - \partial_{k} g(\partial_{i},\partial_{j}) \biggr) \\\\
& =\frac{1}{2}\biggl(\partial_{i}g_{jk} + \partial_{j}g_{ki} - \partial_{k}g_{ij}\biggr)
\end{align}

and replacing, $\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\partial_{j}$ with $\sum_{l=1}^{n}\Gamma_{ij}^{l} \partial_{l}$ we get:
$$
g\biggl(\sum_{l=1}^{n} \Gamma_{ij}^{l}\partial_{l}, \partial_{k}\biggr) = \frac{1}{2}\biggl(\partial_{i}g_{jk} + \partial_{j}g_{ki} - \partial_{k}g_{ij}\biggr)
$$

I know that the metric is a bilinear map but I don't see why the Christoffel symbols would come out since they're functions, not scalars.

Comment: You are done. They are scalar functions. Everything here is a (pointwise) statement about functions.